# Stackoverflow due to large return type of a function

Tags: c++, function, stack-overflow, return-type

this my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

array< array<int, 1000>, 1000 > largeThing;

array< array<int, 1000>, 1000 > functionFoo() {        
    return largeThing;
}

void main(){
    functionFoo();
    return;
}
```

If i run this i get a Stackoverflow error. I've got so far that the reason for this is the large return type of *functionFoo()*, because the return value is actually on the Heap.

### **Question:**

How to use a function with a large return type so that all the memory that the function will put on the stack will be put on the heap instead?

### Edit:

I just increased the stacksize, it worked fine.

Comment: Allocate then pass in by reference, or pass out by pointer.  `big_thing* my_big_thing_maker(int n_things_to_make)`.  For pass out by pointer the function does a new or malloc

Comment: `because the return value is actually on the Heap` You mean "on the stack". If you wish to put it on the heap, then use pointers/refs or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::array` is allocated on the stack, which depending on your build settings can be relatively small (a typical size is 1 MiB).

If you need something bigger you may explicitly allocate that array on the heap and return a pointer. The [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) in this example is a smart pointer that takes care of deallocation when the pointer goes out of scope, so we don't have to remember calling `delete`.

```
using bigarray = std::array< std::array<int, 1000>, 1000 >;

std::unique_ptr< bigarray > functionFoo() {        
   return std::make_unique< bigarray >();
}
```

Another way would be to use a different class that already manages memory on the heap, for instance [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > functionFoo() {        
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > largeThing( 1000, std::vector<int>( 1000 ) );
    return largeThing;
}
```

Comment: @Sopel I would always prefer `std::array` or `std::vector` as they have a `size()` member.

Comment: depends on need, he uses constant size so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: in this case, when size is known at compile time, `std::array` is probably better though

Answer (score 5):

By far the easiest solution is to use `vector` instead of `array`. This will use `std::allocator` aka "the heap".

Comment: The problem is that i have to use arrays because it is a timecritical application.

Comment: @Tsoj What impact did using a vector have in your time critical application? Your starting point is code that segfaults, so it is possible you haven't had the opportunity to carefully profile working code.

Comment: i am writing a new moveGenerator for an existing chess-program and if i am right if i want access an element of an vector i have to search through the half elementspace of the vector at average. Correct me if that time is so small that its worth it to give it a try.

Comment: If you never *add elements* to a vector after it is constructed, it never has to reallocate anything. If you do *add elements* you couldn't have done it with an array

Comment: @Tsoj pretty much anything you can do with a static array, you can do with a vector, as it is just a wrapper for an array allocated on the heap.

Comment: oh, i thought a vector is something like a linked list that doesnt allow random access.  :P